# React Navigation, how to go back to specific screens?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm using `react-navigation:^1.0.0-beta.9` is there a way to go back to specific screen (not the previous one to the current)? I've also integrated my `react-navigation` with `redux`. I've looked into the documentation and saw that `back` accepts a `key` param however this is unclear to me and tried placing in the name of the Screen like `back({ key: 'Screen B' })` but it doesn't work probably because it's expecting a `key` which is randomly generated unless specified specifically.

For example I have this `StackNavigator`

```
Screen A
- Screen B
  - Screen C
    - Screen D (Current)
```

Let's say I am currently on `Screen D` and I wanted to go back to `Screen B` how would I achieve it?

I don't want to use `navigation.navigate('Screen B')` because that's gonna add another screen to the stack and not what I'm expecting.

Comment: I find out that you can use this.props.navigation.goBack("keyOfC"), if you want go to B use keyOfC. It has to be key not route name. BTW, I don't know how to set the key manually.

Comment: @KimHau yeah I noticed that too. But that `key` is randomly generated I believe.

Answer (score 15):

1.Inside `screen D` dispatch some action:

```
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    navigation.dispatch({
        routeName: 'B',
        type: 'GoToRoute',
    });
```

2.Handle this action in MyStackNavigator.js

```
const MyStackNavigator = new StackNavigator(//...);
const defaultGetStateForAction = MyStackNavigator.router.getStateForAction;
MyStackNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {            
    if (state && action.type === 'GoToRoute') {           
        let index = state.routes.findIndex((item) => {
            return item.routeName === action.routeName
        });
        const routes = state.routes.slice(0, index+1);
        return {
            routes,
            index
        };    
    }       
    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

and then you can go from `screen D` to `screen B` directly

Comment: I had to add `...state` to the returned object to avoid "Cannot get config because the route does not have a routeName" error: `return { ...state, routes, index }`

Comment: This saved my project, they really need to improve their navigation options.

Comment: Do you know of anyway to remove showing the previous screens?

Comment: Works like Charm :) This should be the accepted Answer :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore because `action.type` is an enum:

`[ts] Operator '===' cannot be applied to types '"Navigation/INIT" | "Navigation/NAVIGATE" | "Navigation/BACK" | "Navigation/SET_PARAMS" | "Naviga...' and '"GoToRoute"'.`